# How to put an image on two different layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

How can I achieve this layout?

[image]

Comment: Use negative margin such as -10dp

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout that act as a parent of a LinearLayout( say layout ll_par) & an ImageView..In your ll_par add your two remaining layout .& remember put the Imageview as the last child of FrameLayout & set its layout_gravity to right|center_vertical & give some margin to your Imageview according to the need ..